# Calling an arraylist in another class

Tags: java, arrays, web-services

So i am doing a web service and i want to call the arraylist from one class to another.

I already tried a few codes but i cant get it, so i came here to see if you can give me a hand and to see if i can finally end this.

My operation on the webservice:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "findHorarioCurso")
public java.util.ArrayList<HorariosCurso> findHorarioCurso(@WebParam(name = "id_curso") int id_curso){
    GereBD bd = new GereBD();
    return bd.findHorarioCurso(id_curso);
}
```

Array:

```
public java.util.ArrayList<HorariosCurso> findHorarioCurso(int id_curso){
    try{
        ArrayList<HorariosCurso> vecHorarioCurso = new ArrayList();
        String query="SELECT h.inicio,h.fim,h.dia,c.designacao_curso,c.ano,u.designacao FROM horario h INNER JOIN cursos c ON c.id_curso=h.id_curso INNER JOIN uc u ON u.id_uc=h.id_uc WHERE h.id_curso = "+id_curso;

        Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
        ResultSet lig = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (lig.next()){
            HorariosCurso Horario = new HorariosCurso();
            Horario.setInicio(lig.getString("inicio"));
            Horario.setFim(lig.getString("fim"));
            Horario.setDia(lig.getString("dia"));
            Horario.setDesignacaoCurso(lig.getString("designacao_curso"));
            Horario.setAno(lig.getInt("ano"));
            Horario.setDesignacao(lig.getString("designacao"));
            vecHorarioCurso.add(Horario);
        }
        return vecHorarioCurso;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Erro de IO" + ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have created the set and gets in a HorariosCurso class:

```
public class HorariosCurso {
    private String inicio;
    private String fim;
    private String dia;
    private String designacao_curso;
    private int ano;
    private String designacao;




    public String getInicio()
    {
        return this.inicio;
    }

    public String getFim()
    {
        return this.fim;
    }

    public String getDia()
    {
        return this.dia;
    }

    public String getDesignacaoCurso()
    {
        return this.designacao_curso;
    }

    public int getAno()
    {
        return this.ano;
    }

     public String getDesignacao()
    {
        return this.designacao;
    }

    public void setInicio(String inicio)
    {
        this.inicio = inicio;
    }

    public void setFim(String fim)
    {
        this.fim = fim;
    }

     public void setDia(String dia)
    {
        this.dia=dia;
    }

    public void setDesignacaoCurso(String designacao_curso)
    {
        this.designacao_curso = designacao_curso;
    }

    public void setAno(int ano)
    {
        this.ano = ano;
    }
    public void setDesignacao(String designacao)
    {
        this.designacao = designacao;
    }
}
```

Client class where im trying to get the info from that arraylist:

```
case 4:
            System.out.println("Encontrar horário de um curso");
            idCurso = sq.nextInt();
            List<HorariosCurso> h = findHorarioCurso(idCurso);
System.out.println(h.get(1).getDesignacao()+h.get(1).getDesignacaoCurso()+h.get(1).getDia()+h.get(1).getFim()+h.get(1).getInicio());
            break;
```

When i press the number of the idCurso, I Want to get the following set's that i 
 have in another class:

```
Horario.setInicio(lig.getString("inicio"));
Horario.setFim(lig.getString("fim"));
Horario.setDia(lig.getString("dia"));
Horario.setDesignacaoCurso(lig.getString("designacao_curso"));
Horario.setAno(lig.getInt("ano"));
Horario.setDesignacao(lig.getString("designacao"));
```

Comment: "not able to do it". How did you try, and what is the error you get?

Comment: the 2nd part of the code is where i try to get the info, i dont get any error, im just not getting the info that i want to

Comment: Is it calling an **array** or **Arraylist** from another class? I hope you know those two are not the same

Comment: ye, i meant arraylist, i mentioned it later but ye, my mistake

Comment: What i see in the code is, that the query seems to retrieve multiple records, all having that same "idCurso" id. Consequently the h.get(idCurso) makes little sense and most probably fails.  Please provide a little more information about what you try to achieve otherwise its difficult to answer.

Comment: As i mentioned, if you look to the other part of the code i have multiple set's, and those are the infos that im trying to get

Comment: You probably will want to clarify your question and problem greatly, including creating and posting a valid [mcve] program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: Fixed it, with more info

Comment: Thank you, but still not sure. I try to guess, that you might want the first record of id "idCurso". " h.get(0)" instead of "h.get(idCurso)"?   "System.out.println(h.get(0).getFim())"  should print something unless the query found nothing(which will result in a crash).

Comment: it prints me just one part, i want the list in that id

Comment: Do you expect to get back multiple `HorariosCurso` instances for a single `idCurso` value? If yes--then why do you do `h.get(idCurso)`? Let's say `idCurso` is 401. You call `findHorarioCurso` and get back 15 `HorariosCurso` instances. If you try to `get` element `idCurso` (401) when there are only 15 elements, you will get an error.

Comment: yes, i expect to get back multiple for a single idCurso

Comment: i edited the code already, but it only gives me 1 instance still :/

Comment: You will **definitely** find your problem if you step through your code with your Debugger. Does your database query actually deliver what you think it does (display the resultset in console)? Is **case 4** actually getting hit?  Does **sq.nextInt()** actually give anything to **idCurso**? Are you ignoring Exceptions...anywhere? Are there actually enough instances of **HorariosCurso** to accept an index value of **1** (hence, ignoring exceptions)? Since you've hardcoded 1 you will only ever get one. And so on, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a for loop:

```
case 4:
        System.out.println("Encontrar horário de um curso");
        idCurso = sq.nextInt();
        List<HorariosCurso> h = findHorarioCurso(idCurso);
        for(HorariosCurso hc:h)
            System.out.println(hc.getDesignacao()+hc.getDesignacaoCurso()+hc.getDia()+hc.getFim()+hc.getInicio());
        break;
```

Comment: it worked thank you, got it all, i was missing the cicle